# Jquery Toggle only works on one Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm having an issue with using Jquery toggle on a feed. I have a hyperlink called Tags. When i click on this it toggles a div underneath it.

It works - But only for the top post in the feed - If I have any other posts in the feed it doesn't work.

Below Is Jquery:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
         $("#hypfeedTagBtn").click(function()  {
             $("#divPostBodyTags").toggle();

             return false;

         });
     });



</script>
```

Below is HTML:-

```
    <div id="divPostFoot_64" class="dPostMain dPostFoot">
<span id="Content_ucFeeds_repFeedThread_lblFeedViewCouont_0" class="spFootReplyCount"></span>
<span id="Content_ucFeeds_repFeedThread_lblFeedShareLink_0" class="spFootLinks"></span>
<span id="Content_ucFeeds_repFeedThread_lblFeedDeleteLink_0" class="spFootLinks"></span>
<a id="hypfeedTagBtn" class="spFootLinksShowTags">Tags</a>
<a id="Content_ucFeeds_repFeedThread_hypFeedMessageMe_0" class="spFootLinks" href="/Mail/NewMessage.aspx?FeedID=64">Message Me</a>
</div>

    <div id="divPostBodyTags" class="dPostMain dPostTAGSDIV" style="display: block;">
<ul id="PostBodyTags">
<li class="TAGLiItem">
<a class="TAGaItem">Plumbers</a>
</li>
<li class="TAGLiItem">
<a class="TAGaItem">Plumbers</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thanks

Steve

Comment: _" But only for the top post in the feed "_ What does that mean, it only hides the first li? or do you have more than one div?

Comment: ID's are supposed to be unique.. so using an ID selector, you will always only get the first element found with that ID

Comment: You can only have one unique id per web page, so toggling should be performed on a class instead.

Answer (score 1):

[MDN element.id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.id)

> **The ID must be unique in a document**, and is often used to retrieve the
>   element using document.getElementById.
>
> In some documents (in particular, HTML, XUL, and SVG), the id of an
>   element can be specified as an attribute on the element like so: .
>
> However you can't use this attribute in a custom XML document without
>   correctly specifying the type of the id attribute in the DOCTYPE.
>
> Other common usages of id include using the element's ID as a selector
>   when styling the document with CSS.
>
> Note that IDs are case-sensitive, but you should not create IDs that
>   differ only in the capitalization (see Case Sensitivity in class and
>   id Names).

Use a class instead of an id if you want to toggle more than one section.

Comment: ok guys - thanks for this. I've changed the ID to a class. Now when I click on the button it togles all the hidden div in all posts at the same time!...anyway to get it to toggle just the div on only one post?

**Posts - I'm building a social network - So if someone sent a post it's an item in there feed. Like facebook, Twitter or Google + would send a post****

Comment: You need to change it to be something like `$(".yourClassOnLinks").click(function(e) { $(this).parent().find(".YourClassOnTheDivsToToggle").toggle(); e.preventDefault(); }`